# Getting SQL from ResultSet Java

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I have a ResultSet Object that I do not know the SQL and params of it.
how I discover ResultSet's SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer? You can't. A `ResultSet` object is independent of the query or stored procedure that produced it.

Comment: using jaybird driver not work, but I read that I can to get using `rs.getStatemant().toString` with JDBC MySQL driver work fine. I don't test.